# Can't update the model in controller with chip value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Looks like something simple is going on here, but I can't figure out what is wrong (learning angularjs still).

I am working on a web chat with quick replies option, the model can be updated from input or from a click on quick reply chip. And the value of chip should be assigned to the model, but there it comes to an issue.

Controller code (same function for input and  quick replies)

```
// sending message
              $scope.sendMessage = function (chip) {
               if(chip != ''){
                 console.log(chip) // getting the chip value correctly
                  $scope.message.text = chip;  // looks like nothing happens here
                    console.log( $scope.message.text)  // undefined 
                      $scope.message.myEntry = true;
                        $scope.messages.push($scope.message);

                        socket.emit('chat message', {
                                myEntry:  $scope.message.myEntry,
                                text: $scope.message.text
                            }
                        );
            }else{
                $scope.message.myEntry = true;
                  $scope.messages.push($scope.message);

                        socket.emit('chat message', {
                                myEntry:  $scope.message.myEntry,
                                text: $scope.message.text
                            }
                        );
                  }
                    // clear message box
                  $scope.message = '';
            };
```

And the code of the view

```
<li class="ChatLog__entry item"
                ng-class="{ChatLog__entry_mine: message.myEntry === true}"
                ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index">
                <img class="ChatLog__avatar" src="//placekitten.com/g/50/50" />
                <p ng-if="message.text" class="ChatLog__message" ng-class="{clientMessage: message.myEntry === true}">{{message.text}}

                   <time class="ChatLog__timestamp"></time>
                </p>
               <md-button ng-if="message.button" class="md-raised md-default" ng-click="gotoState(message.button.state)">{{message.button.value}}</md-button>
                <md-chips class="quick_replies" ng-if="message.quick_replies" ng-model="message.quick_replies"  
                readonly="true">
                <md-chip-template  ng-model="message.text" readonly="true" md-removable="false" 
                ng-click="sendMessage($chip)">{{$chip}}</md-chip-template>
                </md-chips>
            </li>
```

Thank you.

Comment: where did you declare   $scope.message ?

Comment: declare  $scope.message = {} like this and try

Comment: @Dinesh Hi, I declared it in my Controller.

Comment: $scope.message = ''; this will again convert object to string. make it same as $scope.message = {}

Comment: @Dinesh , thanks for the help, that fixed the issue with quick reply but had to add additional check and param to the function that running after input field submission. Even though I still can't get what is the issue, and why the way you suggested didn't work  for both, quick reply click and input submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.message = '';` this will again convert object to string. 
Change this line as

```
$scope.message = {};
```